# Label with for tag positioned outside of intended element

Tags: html, css

I have a form that has a few basic input controls on it. Each one has a label with a span used for displaying error messages upon validation.

The issue is that for some reason that I cannot seem to figure out when I click the submit button with an error on the form the label shows but it shows up at the bottom of the form beside the submit button instead of inside the element input control where the error is.

When I inspect the page the label is in the correct dom of the form but the positioning is off even though I am using the absolute position.

Form code

```html
<section>
  <div class="block color-scheme-1">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-2  col-md-offset-2">
          <div class="section-sub-title center">
            <article class="section-title-body white">
              <h1 class="head-title"><span>Adress</span> Information</h1>
            </article>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center white">
            <h4 class="widget-title">Mosaic Design Studio <br><br>Avanue street 255, NA</h4>

          </div>
          <div class="text-center white">
            <p>(10 808) 321-1785-952
              <br>(10 808) 321-1785-953
            </p>
            <p>mosaic-design@domain.com
              <br>support@yoursite.com
            </p>
            <br>
            <br>
          </div>
          <div class="section-sub-title center">
            <article class="section-title-body white">
              <h1 class="head-title"><span>Send</span> Massage</h1>
            </article>
          </div>
          <div id="form-wrapper">
            <div id="form-inner">
              <div id="ErrResults">
                <!-- Error Here -->
              </div>
              <div id="MainResult">
                <!-- Response Here -->
              </div>
              <div id="MainContent">
                <form id="MyContactForm" name="MyContactForm" method="post">
                  <p class="name">
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name">
                    <label for="name" id="nameLb"><span class="error">*Name Field Required</span>
                    </label>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email">
                    <label for="email" id="emailLb">
                      <span class="error error1">*Email Field Required</span> 
                      <span class="error error2">*Email Not Valid</span>
                    </label>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Your Telephone">
                    <label for="phone" id="phoneLb"><span class="error">*Telephone Field Required</span>
                    </label>
                  </p>
                  <p class="textarea">
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message" rows="4"></textarea>
                    <label for="message" id="messageLb"><span class="error">*Message Field Required</span>
                    </label>
                  </p>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <a href="#" class="contact-btn">Send Message</a> 
                  </div>

                </form>
              </div>
              <!--MainContent-->
            </div>
            <!--form-inner-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```css
#form-wrapper #MyContactForm .error {
  bottom: 30px;
  color: #FF2255;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  left: auto;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute` from your `.error`

[Demo](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/BQPOWp)

You have set absolute position to your errors, without setting relative position to their container. So they are being positioned in relation to something further up on your page.

UPDATE:
To position the errors inside the input you need to add `position:relative` to the `p` tag. You should probably assign a class to those p tags you wish to target, so that it doesn't clash with p tags elsewhere on the page, if there are any.

Example:

```
p {
   position: relative;
}
```

Then use absolute positioning on .error, and some positioning coordinates, like this:

```
.error {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 3px;
}
```

You'll notice that your error is in the input box, and clashes with the input placeholder. You'll likely need a script to hide the placeholder when an error is showing.

[Updated demo](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/BQPOWp)

NOTE: I'm not sure it's standard to place error messages in the input box. Might be a lot easier to just have it show beside?

Comment: OK, so I removed the position tag and now the label shows below input instead of inside.

Comment: Nice ovokuro, the position on the p tag was what was missing! Thank you so much!